# Stack Overflow "An error occured with login"

Tags: discussion

I've registered an identity with Stack Overflow using my real name (my GMail account obviously is not my real name!), and after successfully registering and confirming my account, all I get when entering my credentials is "An error occurred with login". I've tried both Firefox AND Safari on Mac, same deal. Is there an issue with Stack Overflow logins using its own username/password system?